"That promised land for which he was to prepare, but scarcely to enter" - why is this wrong rather than awkward?
In the section "Relatives: coordination" of the book "The King's English", the Fowlers write:

In our next example, Lord Rosebery, again for fear of a preposition at the end, falls into the trap clumsily avoided by the "Times" writer:

That promised land for which he was to prepare, but scarcely to enter


The sentence by the "Times" writer is:

A demand by Norway for political separation, to which Sweden will not assent, but will not go to war to prevent it

I think the Fowlers are saying that the coordination is no good and that the "which" is causing a problem; the Rosebery sentence looks awkward to me and I think I could rewrite it so that the Fowlers would be ok with it - but I don't see why that sentence is incorrect rather than awkward

lose the apostrophe - the Fowlers.

I do not understand those sentences in terms of your comments about them. Please clarify.

The problem with Rosebery's phrase becomes obvious if you move the for into the relative clause:

that promised land which he was to prepare for, but scarcely to enter for.

The issue is that prepare, in the relevant sense, takes as a complement a prepositional phrase with the preposition for, but enter just takes a direct object; for which can't serve as a complement for both.

I found this very helpful, thank you

You put in another for after enter?

@Lambie Yes, because that illustrates what's wrong with the original sentence: the "for" in "for which" has to go in the gap after prepare as well as the gap after enter.

I simply don't get it. This: /That promised land for which he was to prepare, but scarcely to enter/ is fine.  You prepare for something, but you don't enter for something. So now what? And what does the OP's second sentence have to do with this one?

Nice exposition.

Perhaps it's not wrong. One could just as easily analyze this with gapping in a coordination (or ellipsis if you prefer).

That promised land
[COORD 1] for which he was to prepare,
but
[COORD 2] (he was) scarcely to enter.

It doesn't sound particularly wrong to my ears, and the correction worse than the original.

It sounds ok to me. And certainly makes sense. But if you're writing a usage book you need to arbitrarily declare some things good and some things bad.

Yes, I think it's fine, too.

alphabet's answer shows how the parallelism fails. But I'm not sure I understand what the intended meaning is in any case.
